# Inbox with getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

I am looking for the best way to implement an inbox with getstream.io

basically, just like the FB out twitter inbox. where a user can send a private message to another one.

I have the save requirement for private discussion groups.

How can I model this with getstream.io ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream supports this use-case very well. My suggestion is to use notification feeds, this way you have read/seen state counters out-of-the-box.

The flow is pretty simple: when a user sends a private message to another user, all you have to do is add an activity to the recipient's notification feed.

```
// John sends a message to Mike
client = stream.connect('key', 'secret')
activity = {'actor': 'user:jhon', 'verb': 'message', 'object': 'message:123'}
client.feed('notification', 'mike').add_activity(activity)
```

If you want, you can also add the same activity to both sender and recipient feeds with a single API call. In this case we add to John's user feed and to Mike's notification feed.

```
client = stream.connect('key', 'secret')
activity = {
    'actor': 'user:john',
    'verb': 'message',
    'object': 'message:123',
    'to': ['notification:mike']
}
client.feed('user', 'john').add_activity(activity)
```

You can find more information about [notification feeds](https://getstream.io/docs/#notification-feeds) and [`to` targeting](https://getstream.io/docs/#targetting) field on Stream documentation pages.